# String comparison not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, opera

this seems to be weird but it really happened.
I have this code working in IE8 and FF but I was shocked its not really working in Google Chrome

```
/*btnPost*/
$("input#btnPost").click(function(){
    //check if the textbox contains anything...
    var txtPostdata = $.trim($("div#txtPost").html());
    if(txtPostdata.length <= 0){
        d = createDialog("confirmation","are you sure to post a blank post?",{"modal":true});
        d.dialog("open");
    }
});
```

the thing that is not working there is the chrome cannot know the length of the **txtPostdata** variable. the **txtPostdata** holds the html that was grabbed in a **CONTENTEDITABLE DIV**.
i tried to pull out the TODO inside the if statement and it works fine. I tried also doing this

```
/*btnPost*/
$("input#btnPost").click(function(){
    //check if the textbox contains anything...
    var txtPostdata = $.trim($("div#txtPost").html());
    if(txtPostdata == ""){
        d = createDialog("confirmation","are you sure to post a blank post?",{"modal":true});
        d.dialog("open");
    }
});
```

but still not working... is there any way i can solve this issue in chrome? my version of chrome is 17.0.

Please try it 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/x3K2g/1/)

Comment: Tested also in Safari and Opera... not working

Comment: Try .innerHTML or .innerText.  To see what's available generally, right-click on the part of your page you're interested in and select "Inspect Element".  The Developer Tools panel should appear, with a bunch of boxes on the right side.  Open "Properties" and select the first "HTML[tag]Element".  It will show you what's inside the accessible properties of the DOM object you have highlighted.

Comment: This must be some issue with your editable div, the `$.trim($("div#txtPost").html()).length` is working just like it should: http://jsfiddle.net/kt4aw/

Comment: The question is: How do you try to empty the div? I tried using DEL and Backspace and I always ended up having at least one `<br>` in the div. Only when I called `$('#txtPost').html("")` it was empty, and `if(txtPostdata.length <= 0)` was working just fine in Chrome http://jsbin.com/asihom/2

Comment: i think jquery's .html() uses already .innerHTML of the browser as said by jquery documentation here http://api.jquery.com/html/
i have no idead about .innerText... can you explain more further? thanks for the answer

Comment: the thing here is the variable can get the html from the editable div... but the chrome has the problem within the if statement... let me double check... thank you

Comment: @devnull69 i empty the div using a DEL and backspace... and tried to use $('#txtPost').html("") only but still not working... i may try it to jsfiddle again

Comment: @CodrinEugeniu please post your answer i gonna give you an upvote and accepted answer ^^ thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used `.text()` instead of `.html()` it worked ok.

```
var txtPostdata = $.trim($("#txtPost").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(txtPostdata==undefined){
        d = createDialog("confirmation","are you sure to post a blank post?",{"modal":true});
        d.dialog("open");
    }
```